# Validation of a single select drop down in MVC 4

Tags: c#, .net, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I have a model that has a property like the following:

```
[Required]
public int SingleSelect { get; set; }
```

Than I set up a SelectList in the controller and pass it t the viewbag

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.SingleSelectList = new SelectList(new[]
                                      {
                                          new {ID="0",Name="-- Select --"},
                                          new {ID="1",Name="Select 1"},
                                          new{ID="2",Name="Select 2"},
                                          new{ID="3",Name="Select 3"},
                                      },
                        "ID", "Name", 0);


        return View();
    }
```

Then on the View() I render a nice drop down box using the following:

```
@Html.LabelFor(obj => obj.SingleSelect, new { @class = "control-label"})
@Html.DropDownListFor(obj => obj.SingleSelect, ViewBag.SingleSelectList as SelectList)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(obj => obj.SingleSelect)

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Validate!</button>
```

How can I get validation to work showing an error if the user hasn't made a selection on form submit (still on option "-- Select --")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try two approaches, firstly

```
[Required, Range(1, Int32.MaxValue)]
public int SingleSelect { get; set; }
```

or change your SelectList:

```
ViewBag.SingleSelectList = new SelectList(new[]
{
    new {ID="0",Name="-- Select --", Value=""},
    new {ID="1",Name="Select 1"},
    new{ID="2",Name="Select 2"},
    new{ID="3",Name="Select 3"},
},
"ID", "Name", 0);
```